# Почему функция PosEx корректно работает в Delphi 7 и некорректно работает в RAD Studio 10 (Delphi)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-10-seattle

Функция в Delphi 7 возвращает правильное значение, в RAD Studio 10 ничего не возвращает. В чем тут дело и как исправить?
Сообщений и ошибок нет.

```
//Функция для получения содержимого между словами
function get_stext(First, Second, Where: string): string;
var
  Pos1, Pos2: Integer;
  WhereLower: string;
begin
  First:=LowerCase(First);
  Second:=LowerCase(Second);
  WhereLower:=LowerCase(Where);
  Assert(Length(WhereLower) = Length(Where));
  Pos1:=PosEx(First, WhereLower, 0);
  Pos2:=PosEx(Second, WhereLower, Pos1);
  Result:=Copy(Where, Pos1 + Length(First), Pos2 - Pos1 - Length(First));
end;

//Пример использования
current_string:='<BEGIN>Some_text</BEGIN>';
programm_path:=get_stext('<BEGIN>','</BEGIN>',current_string);
MEMO1.Lines.Add(programm_path) ;
```

В Delphi 7 в поле MEMO1 будет Some_text. 
В RAD Studio 10 - пусто (знак переноса при выполнении Lines.Add).

Comment: так пройдитесь отладчиком, просматривая содержимое переменных. И всё встанет на свои места.

Comment: P.S. если нужно работать с xml - то не стоит разбирать его как текст. Для этого есть модуль XML.XMLDoc

Comment: PS
Написал ответ.
И если нужно работать с xml - то не.../и тут что говорят постоянно/
Разумеется есть куча всего что работает с xml во всех средах, языках, но..большинству русскоязычных фирм - например Ростелеком - наплевать на стандарты. Да и вообще на любые стандарты.

И это значит, что никакие модули просто не заработают с их выдуманным xml. И тут 2 варианта - либо приводить их поделку к стандарту и юзать модули, либо парсить как текст.
Горькая правда жизни. (

Comment: а может вы просто не умеете работать с хмл?

Answer (score 1):

надо было исправить вот так (0 на 1)

```
Pos1:=PosEx(First, WhereLower, 1);
```

Comment: Т.е. вы изначально неправильно использовали функцию `PosEx`. И в Delphi 7 оно вам сходило с рук, а вот в более новой версии - нет.

Comment: А зачем там вообще PosEx? `Pos1 := Pos(First, WhereLower)` не подходит?

Comment: _"**If** SubStr is not found or **Offset is** invalid (greater than the length of S or **less than 1), then the result is 0**. "_ RTFM